# Ampscript - Troubleshooting a checkbox

Tags: ampscript, html, inputcheckboxes, form

I am trying to determine if a checkbox is sending the correct value to salesforce when I use the UpdateSingleSalesforceObject function, is there anyway to determine this from the string on the thank you page or otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Is this is a static value? If it is, you may be able to use the Substring(S1, I1, I2) function and check that the value is equal to the correct value and append the return statement to the url for the thank you page.